# how to fix undefined values with functions

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm making a program that searches through an object and prints the properties of that object to the console. The program compiles and runs, but the only thing that prints to the console is `undefined`. How do I fix this?

```js
function printInfo(array) {
  var usersLength = array.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < usersLength; i++) {
    console.log("Name: ", array.name, "Role: ", array.role);
    return array.name, array.role;
  }
}
```

This function would be passed an object with certain properties inside ( `name`, `role`, `dob`). The expected result is that these values would print. But what actually prints is "undefined".

Comment: Try array[i].name..

Comment: Closing it as a simple error.

Comment: Do you know what the comma operator is?

Comment: no what is the comma operator? and thank you richard your suggestion worked

Comment: also i feel a little slow missing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bobby

this will return undefined and an error on your console:

> return array.name, array.role;

array.name property does not exist try this so you know what value function parameter has

```
console.log(array)
```

more about arrays look on this site https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Answer (score -1):

If you had ES6, then use:

```
const printInfo = array => {
    for(let info in array){
        console.log(info);
    }
}
```